# Template specialization restricted by a condition

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Is it possible to make compiler choose between template specifications depending on type traits? For example, consider two template implementations of a Compare functional, one for sequential types (`string`s, `vector`s, `list`s, etc.) and another one for integer types. Can we have only one template specialization for the each class of types?

```
template <class SeqT>
class Compare
{
public:
   bool operator()(const SeqT& s1, const SeqT& s2) const
   {
      typename SeqT::const_iterator it1=s1.begin();
      typename SeqT::const_iterator it2=s2.begin();
      while(it1!=s1.end() && it2!=s2.end())
      {
         if(*it1<*it2) return true;
         if(*it2<*it1) return false;
         ++it1; ++it2;
      }
      return it2!=s2.end();
   }
};

template <class IntegerT>
class Compare
{
public:
   bool operator()(IntegerT i1, IntegerT i2) const
   {
      return i1<i2;
   }
};

template <class T, class Cmp = Compare<T> >
class SomeContainer
{
   ...
};
```

Basically, what I am looking for is a way to partially specialize a template by imposing a condition on the template argument. Like the first `Compare<>` specialization should be applied to the following types: `std::basic_string<>`, `std::vector<>`, `std::list<>`, and the second for the following types: `int`, `unsigned`, `short`, `char`. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. Look into std::enable_if

Comment: I thought of `std::enable_if` first, but I think it's better to add a template parameter that indicates the kind of type, and that can be TMP "computed" from the basic type. Then just provide specializations.

Comment: What do you mean by sequence -- do you mean any object that can be iterated over using the `for (auto x : y)` syntax?

Answer (score 3):

This is my answer to another question, but it is what you need. It uses SFINAE to create template specialization ONLY for the template arguments that test true for a condition (like beeing a specific type).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20898554/2805305

**Edit**

> But how can I exactly specify that the first Compare specialization can be applied to e.g. std::basic_string and std::vector?

You create a trait that tells you if T is a vector or basic_string or list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct is_seq : std::false_type {
};

template <class T>
struct is_seq<std::vector<T>> : std::true_type {
};

template <class T>
struct is_seq<std::basic_string<T>> : std::true_type {
};

template <class T>
struct is_seq<std::list<T>> : std::true_type {
};

template <class T>
using enable_if_seq_type = typename std::enable_if<is_seq<T>::value>::type;

template <class T>
using enable_if_integral_type = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type;


template <class T, class Enable = void>
class Compare; // <--------  define if you want a Compare for any type that doesn't match any specialization

template <class T>
class Compare<T, enable_if_seq_type<T>> { // specialization for T a vector, string or list
    public:
        void foo() {
            cout << "vector, string and list specialization" << endl;
        }
};

template <class T>
class Compare<T, enable_if_integral_type<T>> { // specialization for T an integral type
    public:
        void foo() {
            cout << "integral specialization" << endl;
        }
};


int main() {
    cout << std::boolalpha;

    cout << is_seq<int>::value << endl; // false
    cout << is_seq<std::vector<int>>::value << endl; // true

    Compare<int> c1; // uses second specialization
    c1.foo(); // output "integral specialization" 

    Compare<std::vector<int>> c2; // uses first specialization
    c2.foo(); // output "vector, string and list specialization"

    //Compare<std::complex<int>> c3;
    // compile error if you just declare and not define the generic Compare.
    // If you define the generic Compare, this will compile and it will use
    // that definition

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/JUbwla

If you want to be able to instantiate the class `Compare` for any other type, then you define the first (general) `Compare` declaration.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I exactly specify that the first Compare specialization can be applied to e.g. std::basic_string<T> and std::vector<T>? Also, I don 't need compile to _fail_, but the compiler to _choose_ the appropriate template when the type argument matches some condition. So, like in the above example, if SomeContainer<std::string> is instantiated, then Compare<SeqT> is used, and if SomeContainer<int> is instantiated, then Compare<IntegerT> is used.

Comment: @bolov The above approach has an issue.  The simple issue is that `std::vector` with unusual allocator, `std::string` with non-default char traits, etc all do not work.  The underlying issue is that maintaining a list of `template` or types that match a condition is often a bad idea, compared to doing some kind of duck-type testing.

Comment: @bolov Thanks for the code example! I can understand the concept of type enablers much better now.

Comment: @Yakk You made a very important point about the default types in template declarations. It is probably not generally acceptable to use type-constrained template specializations.